# Relative clauses

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I have these two sentences:

> "**All of them** knew the criminals by sight. The local police arrested them."

If you were asked to join them using a relative clause, how would you do it?
*all of them* is the part to substitute with a relative pronoun.

I think:

> "The local police, who knew the criminals by sight, arrested them."

is correct.

Comment: Who exactly are *all of them*? Are they the police or not? And who are *them* in the second sentence? I mean the sentence could be, *The local police arrested all those who knew the criminals by sight*.

Comment: all of them is referred to the police.

Comment: in the second sentence them is referred to the criminals.

Comment: In that case your sentence is fine. But, the part in quotation marks should begin with a capital letter.

Comment: @WS2 I agree.  It's confusing.  Without any context, my initial assumption is that "them" in both sentences has the same antecedent.  Another possible answer: *All of them knew the criminals whom the local police arrested by sight.*